# Fenton's reagent application to leachate

Tags: oxidation-state

What is the experimental procedure for applying fenton's reagent to leachate? What doses of hydrogen peroxide and ferrous sulphate required? How much contact time needs to be provided?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se? Lern more about this site in the [help] and taking the [tour]. I am not very certain if [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235748994_Optimization_of_semi-aerobic_stabilized_leachate_treatment_using_ozoneFenton%27s_reagent_in_the_advanced_oxidation_process) contains the information you are looking for, but it might get you started.

Comment: @Martin maybe the OP doesn't have access to the Researchgate. I myself couldn't make an account because I don't have an institution or anything.